# Array out of bounds checking (with a function)

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am new to C programming and I had 2 questions about my homework assignment that was turned in. I am not asking how to do anything, I am asking about what I did wrong ( my TA said I did two things wrong). I had to use this two functions. (Sorry for the long question. I am new to this website as well so I do not know if this is an appropriate   question as well).

These were the numbers given in my homework and here are my codes for insert and second.

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};

void insert(int a[], int size, int key, int k){

    a[k] = key;

}
```

My TA had said that I did not check to see if k was within the index and I am sorta confused on how to check for the. I wanted to know how because I know it will be important for future projects within my majors.

For the second function, I had to grab the largest second largest element in the array and put it into the zeroth element. The only problem with that was it had put 12 into the zeroth element rather 11. I never understood on how to do it.

```
void second(int a[], int size){

int j = 0;

int b, c, i = 0;

int temp = 0;

int pos,pos1;

for ( b = 0; b<(size-1); b++){
    if(a[b] < a[b+1]){
        pos = b+1;
    }
}
for (b = 0; b<(size-1); b++){
    if ( a[i] < a[b+1] && pos != b-1){
        pos1 = b+1;
        i++;
    }

    temp = a[0];
    a[0] = a[pos1];
    a[pos1] = temp;
}
```

Thank you for the help! (Any other comments are acceptable, such as if my coding is bad, I think it is).

Comment: In your `second()` function, I'm not sure what your algorithm is.  It is not clear, but presumably the data in the array is not sorted.  If by some mischance, the data was in reverse order, so `a[0] >= a[1] && a[1] >= a[2] && … && a[size-2] >= a[size-1]`, then `pos` will not be set. If it is set, it will be the last position where an earlier element is larger than its next door later element. This isn't obviously useful. If you don't sort the array first, you'd need to do some sort of trickery such a `int min1 = a[0]; int min2 = a[0]; for (int b = 1; b < size; b++) { if (a[b] > min2) { … } }`.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. I see what you are getting at.

Comment: I upvoted a homework question!  I'm bookmarking this event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your TA was right, you should check the index is within the bounds of the array.

```
void insert(int a[], int size, int key, int k) {
    if (k < 0 || k >= size) {
        // error: k out of bound!
        return;
    }
    a[k] = key;
}
```

To find the 2nd largest element within the array, and put it into a[0], you can do this in one pass of loop:

```
void second(int a[], int size) {
    int first, second;
    int i;

    first = 0;
    second = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (a[i] > a[first]) {
            second = first;
            first = i;
        } else if (a[i] > a[second] && a[i] != a[first])
            second = i;
    }

    int temp = a[0];
    arr[0] = a[second];
    a[second] = a[0];
}
```

Comment: In order to track the second largest, have to track the largest one, so whenever found a element that is larger than the largest, that becomes the largest, and the old largest becomes  the 2nd largest, but when the element is smaller than largest but bigger than 2nd largest, the largest remains unchanged, but need to update the 2nd largest to this element.

Comment: Thank you. I understand everything.

Answer (score 3):

First question:
Check if `k` is within bounds `0..(size-1)`

```
if ((k>=0)&&(k<size))
    a[k] = key;
```

Second question:
`for` loop should be until `size`, not until `size-1`.
Try grouping the terms in `if` statement:

```
if ( (a[b] < a[b+1]) && (pos != b-1))
```

Comment: So, first for loop, it should be for ( b = 0; b<size;...) and for both if statements? Because for one of them I did group them.